# Encapsulamento e métodos Get e Set

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, encapsulamento

Estou continuando meus estudos em programação em Java orientado a objeto.

Atualmente estou estudando encapsulamento e métodos `get` e `set` e me deparei com o seguinte exercício:

> Encapsule o atributo valor da classe Boleto.
>
> Esse atributo não deve ser Settado diretamente. O usuário da classe informa o valor e o aluno. Se o aluno for aprovado é concedido um desconto de 10% no valor do boleto e o método get deve exibir o valor com o desconto concedido.

E criei este código:

Classe Aluno:

```
package Academico;

public class Aluno {

    public String nome;
    private String matricula;
    private String curso;
    protected Disciplina disciplina[];

}
```

Classe Disciplina:

```
package Academico;

public class Disciplina {

    String nome;
    double nota1, nota2, nota3, nota4;
   
}
```

Classe Boleto:

```
package Financeiro;

import Academico.*;

public class Boleto {

    private Aluno aluno;
    private String referencia;
    private double valor;
    
    public Boleto(Aluno aluno, String referencia, double valor){
        this.aluno = aluno;
        this.referencia = referencia;
        this.valor = valor;
    }
    
    public double desconto() {
        disciplina = new Disciplina[3];
        if(disciplina == true){
            this.valor = this.valor-(this.valor*0.1);
            return this.valor;
        }
    }
    
    public double getValorDesconto() {
        return this.valor;
    }

}
```

Existe algum erro na construção do código, no encapsulamento e nos métodos `Get` e `Set`?

Comment: Tem alguma dúvida específica. Não sei o que fazer com essa pergunta, porque a resposta é "está tudo certo" :) Claro que os requisitos indicam problema. Parece que o código não faz o que está sendo determinado. Tem coisas que não fazem o menor sentido, mas não no que está sendo perguntado.

Comment: Eu criei um outro pacote para estudar o encapsulamento. Este outro pacote se chama academico e tem uma classe Aluno e uma classe Disciplina. Ai quis importar o Aluno e a Disciplina do outro pacote.
Ai criei uns métodos antes para verificar se estava ok.
Então o código está totalmente correto em relação ao que o exercício pedia?

Comment: Sem todas informações, é difícil dizer se está tudo certo, me parece que o uso de pacotes está errado, mas o de métodos `get` não.

Comment: É que o exercício dizia que não podia ser settado os atributos diretamente, então retirei os métodos set e só deixei os get.

Comment: Editei o código e coloquei o pacote academico e como eu criei as classes dentro dele para importar para o pacote financeiro. Assim vc pode dar um olhada melhor no código.

Comment: Separe suas classes na pergunta, o código está amontoado, fica dificil entender desse jeito.

Comment: É que não peguei o jeito da edição aqui no fórum ainda, como separar tudo certinho.

Comment: Adicionei a classe Aluno e Disciplina e editei a classe boleto para ficar mais fácil o entendimento do código, se está correto de acordo com o exercício ou não e também já aproveitar para verificar se está correto a construção dos encapsulamentos.

Comment: @Gon 
A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como, veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você e ajudar a todos entender isso. Também pode votar em qualquer coisa no site todo.

Answer (score 1):

> A pergunta foi editada, eu fiz baseado no [código original postado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/120249/1)

O exercício já parece ser bem mal definido. Então fica até difícil dizer o que está certo. Sem informações mais precisas não dá para dizer ou ajudar fazer o certo, não diz o que é o certo.

Pra não ficar sem resposta vou dar uma ligeira melhoradinha e fazer questionamentos:

```
package Financeiro;

import Academico.Disciplina;

public class Boleto {
    private Aluno aluno;
    private String referencia; //o exercício não fala disto
    private double valor; //seria melhor usar um BigDecimal, mas para exercício ok

    public Boleto(Aluno aluno, String referencia, double valor){
        this.aluno = aluno;
        this.referencia = referencia;
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    public Aluno getAluno() { return aluno; }

    public String getReferencia() { return referencia; }

    public double getValor() { return valor; }

    public double desconto() { //isto faz e retorna o desconto, o nome não é bom
        disciplina = new Disciplina[3]; //isto não parece fazer o menor sentido,nem compila
        if (disciplina) { //onde está a verificação de aprovação?
            valor -=  valor * 0.1;
            return valor;
        }
    }

    public double getValorDesconto() { //qual o intuito disto? O requisito não pede
        return valor; //isto parece estar errado se o método faz sentido existir
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/Encapsulation.java).

Possivelmente faltam métodos `set`, mas sei lá se era pra fazer isto. O fato de dizer que o atributo não deve ser *setado*  diretamente é que ele não deve ser público e, em tese, pode ser *setado* indiretamente através de um método `setXXX()`.

O que impede de chamar o desconto várias vezes e até zerar o valor? Eu sei que pra um exercício isto não deve ser muito importante, mas é algo pra se pensar.

Eu acho que o cálculo do desconto deve ser feito no construtor e não existir o método `desconto`, aí acho que resolve melhor.

Um código possivelmente um pouco melhor:

```
public class Boleto {
    private Aluno aluno;
    private String referencia;
    private double valor;

    public Boleto(Aluno aluno, String referencia, double valor) {
        this.aluno = aluno;
        this.referencia = referencia;
        this.valor = valor * (aluno.ÉAprovado() ? 0.9 : 1;
    }
    public double getValor() { return valor; }
}
```

Obviamente o método `ÉAprovado()` faz parte da classe `Aluno`, afinal esta é uma propriedade do aluno e deve ser definida lá. O boleto é só um consumidor da informação do aluno. Cada classe com sua responsabilidade. Ele terá um algoritmo olhando pelas notas do aluno nas disciplinas e retornará um booleano indicado a condição do aluno. A aprovação poderia até ser definido por um classe de política, mas que não é necessária para este algoritmo.

Comment: O new Disciplina [3], eu tinha pensado em vetorizar, para chamar o número de disciplina que ele é matricula, pois se for pensar em faculdade, alguns alunos são matriculados em 3, 4, 5 matérias e assim por diante.
No método do desconto seria melhor colocar protected então, para não poder chamar até zerar o valor? Estas são minhas dúvidas em encapsulamento, quando usar cada um.

Comment: Não tem nada de `protected`, não use coisas que você não sabe usar e não consegue justificar seu uso. Isto não resolve problema algum. A única solução decente é o método não existir. Mas como eu disse, está difícil fazer alguma coisa certa quando a definição não é boa. O código que cuida das notas está completamente errado, nem compila.

Comment: Acho que vc não precisava passar para a ignorância. Eu só queria tirar uma dúvida, eu sei a teoria do public, private e protected. A maneira que vc disse, eu tinha entendido que deveria usar um protected ou private. O que eu não poderia usar seria colocar o desconto no construtor, porque não saberia fazer e nem justificar.

Comment: Onde tem ignorância? Estou dizendo o que eu acho que você deve fazer. Não quer aceitar minha recomendação, faça do jeito que quiser.

Comment: Eu aceitei! Estou até refazendo o código e você está me ajudando bastante, eu só achei meio ofensivo esta parte: "Não tem nada de protected, não use coisas que você não sabe usar e não consegue justificar seu uso."
Eu estudei o public, protected e o private, eu só não entendi bem ainda o momento de utilizar cada um deles. O que vc disse tem total sentido, de chamar até zerar o valor.
Também peço desculpas de minha parte caso fui ofensivo em algum momento, não é minha intenção, só quero aprender corretamente.

Comment: Não quer mais ajudar?